# Simple way to rig an "Activity monitor" for a Twisted socket Factory

Tags: twisted, admin, monitor

I'd like to have a real-time 'system status'/'activity monitor' console for my Twisted application.

The app is basically a protocol.ServerFactory which accepts connections performs different jobs.

Kind of like the twisted.manhole, I'm looking for the simplest way to create a admin application where I can check the current stats of my app.

The admin can be a simple ascii-based shell or html/json setup.

I'm aware that I could build this with a bunch of counters, a separate protocol for authenticating and monitoring these, but I'm thinking Twisted might already have such thing since it at least knows the number of connections, protocol types, etc etc.

Tips?

Comment: Don't real time server monitoring tools help? All you would have to do would be feed a command once, and it will give you the status at the interval you need. Try [SeaLion](https://sealion.com).

Answer (score 2):

There's the unmaintained, slowly rotting `twisted.internet.gladereactor`.  If you're using twistd, then you can use this trivally:

```
twistd --reactor debug-gui ...
```

If you're running the reactor directly yourself, then it's only slightly more effort:

```
from twisted.manhole import gladereactor
gladereactor.install()
from twisted.internet import reactor
...
```

The **Inspect** feature appears to have been broken for some time, but it will still show you a list of established connections and what state they are in, and it will also apparently give you a traffic log for each connection.  Fixing **Inspect** may also be a fairly straightforward effort, in case you're looking for a little project. :)